# javascript, access other members during anonymous object creation?

Tags: javascript, this, member, anonymous

Trying to get the following code to work; As the store variable is assigned an anonymous object, the "data" property is populated using a function call. This setting should also set the contents of the other object's property "masterData". I expected the "this" keyword to refer to the anonymous object being created, but I'm wrong...

```
    var store = {

        masterData : [],

        revert: function() {

            this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData);
        },

        data: (function() {

            var overviewData = getOverviewData();
            this.masterData = overviewData;
            return chartData;

            }).call(),
    };
```

See also that "revert" property; It's given a function that'll create a copy of the object's data property contents.

What should be used, since "this" returns the DOMWindow object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` function is being called before the object is defined; `this` will not be an alias to an object prior to that object's coming into existence. You can use a constructor function with a private, short-lived variable:

```
var getOverviewData = function () { return "I'm overview data!" }
var chartData = "I'm chart data!"

var store = new function () {
  var _masterData
  this.revert = function() {
    this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData)
  }
  this.data = (function() {
    _masterData = getOverviewData()
    return chartData
  }).call()
  this.masterData = _masterData
}()

console.log(store)
// { revert: [Function],
//   data: 'I\'m chart data!',
//   masterData: 'I\'m overview data!' }
```

Comment: Indeed, makes sense... I'll refactor accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem and i solved it by just sending the scope with the function.

```
    var self = this;
    setInterval( yourFunction(self), 1000);

    yourFunction:function( self )
    {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(self);
    }
```

you see when it logs "this" it refers to the DOM and the self is refering to where ever you came from. i hope this helps! :)

EDIT:
instead of inside Data to set the masterData, set the Master data after the Data is created.

```
var store = {

    masterData : [],

    revert: function() {

        this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData);     //Here is where you create data
        masterData = this.data.overviewData;       //set the masterData
    },

    data: (function() {

        var overviewData = getOverviewData();
        return chartData;

        }).call(),
};
```

i think this should work, otherwise sorry :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The problem here is to obtain a pointer to the object being created. Data, revert and masterData are three members of this anonymous objects. And the definition of data needs to access the "masterData" member.

Comment: I think when you give the data the reference (self), you can say: self.masterdata = overviewData; (also in this case the name "self" isnt very clear though XD

Comment: sadly it's not possible to data: (var me = this; function() {

            var overviewData = getOverviewData();
            me.masterData = overviewData;
            return chartData;

            }).call(),
:(

Comment: Nice try :) But I guess the explanation to this is like Richard mentions in an other answer below: "this will not be an alias to an object prior to that object's coming into existence". Thanks anyway!

Comment: The `self` idea doesn't really work (and is usually an antipattern even when it does work). In the IIFE that sets `data`, `store` does not exist so there's no way to access `this` to assign a `self` variable to. It's adding another layer of indirection but doesn't avoid the fact that `this` (referring to `store`) and `store` itself doesn't exist. I'm not sure what the `setInterval` is supposed to do. The "workaround" in the second snippet is totally different logic.

Answer (score 1):

change the flolowing line

```
}).call(),
```

to

```
})()
```

or, if you really want to use the `call` method :

```
 }).call(store)
```

Comment: Using an IIFE means `this` is the `window` and `store` is undefined in `call(store)`.

Answer (score 0):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) won't refer to the current object when the anonymous function is called because it doesn't follow the `obj.func()` pattern which sets `this` in the `func` scope to `obj` and is not bound by some other means. Instead, it refers to the [global window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) (or `undefined` in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) don't help since the `store` object hasn't been defined yet so there's no object to give as a `thisArg` parameter. On the other hand, with `store.revert`, `this` refers to `store` by the time it's called and behaves as expected.

The example seems overly contrived because there's no obvious motivation for setting `masterData` as a side effect of the anonymous function that also sets `data`. It seems you could just do something like:

```js
// some sameple funcs and data for testing purposes
var getOverviewData = function () { return [42]; };
var shallowCopy = function (a) { return a.slice(); };
var chartData = [24];

var store = {
  masterData: getOverviewData(),

  revert: function () {
    this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData);
  },

  data: chartData,
};

console.log(store.data);
store.revert();
console.log(store.data);
```

In general, if a pattern seems awkward to apply, it's often unnecessary or is a suboptimal way to achieve the desired result. The `data` IIFE setter proposed by OP breaks rules of thumb: it doesn't have single responsibility and causes a side effect by mutating an object.

Now, assuming you really do need to access `this` from an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) while defining this property (or for future readers who do have a legitimate motivation), there are multiple ways to achieve this.

The most obvious and direct solution is to create the `store` object and then add the data and mutate it in a second step:

```js
var getOverviewData = function () { return [42]; };
var shallowCopy = function (a) { return a.slice(); };
var chartData = [24];

var store = {
  masterData: [],

  revert: function () {
    this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData);
  },
};
store.data = (function () {
  this.masterData = getOverviewData();
  return chartData;
}).call(store);

console.log(store.data);
store.revert();
console.log(store.data);
```

If you don't like this as two steps, you can toss it in an IIFE:

```js
var getOverviewData = function () { return [42]; };
var shallowCopy = function (a) { return a.slice(); };
var chartData = [24];

var store = (function () {
  var store = {
    masterData: [],

    revert: function () {
      this.data = shallowCopy(this.masterData);
    },
  };
  store.data = (function () {
    this.masterData = getOverviewData();
    return chartData;
  }).call(store);
  return store;
})();

console.log(store.data);
store.revert();
console.log(store.data);
```

An alternative is using a constructor function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332128/6243352) and invoking it with [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) which gives you access to the `this` context.

The IIFE you're using could be a separate function entirely that accepts an object as a parameter and mutates the two properties on it but this is only mentioned for completeness; it's probably only useful if you plan to reuse the function for multiple objects, in which case you might as well create a full-blown [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) or non-IIFE constructor function.